# RestSharp: Error "expected type: JSONObject, found: Null"

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am using RestSharp library for my REST APIs, and I am getting 400 BadRequest "expected type: JSONObject, found: Null"  for GET request. With Postman it is working fine.

```
{
  "Result": {
    "RequestId": "495f45c0-d9e9-11eb-9936-02a74f481686",
    "OverallStatus": "FAILURE",
    "ErrorDetails": [
      {
        "ErrorLineItem": {
          "ErrorCode": "400",
          "ErrorMessage": "Bad Request",
          "ErrorDescription": "expected type: JSONObject, found: Null"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is my code:

```
var request = new GetAlertProfileDistributionChannelRequest
            {
                AccountCustomerNumber = "*****201",
                DistributionChannelSubscriptions = new AlertProfileDistributionChannelSubscriptions
                {
                    AlertProfileId = Guid.Parse("7adaaa2c-5b2d-424c-8dc8-4e9a01908729")
                }
            };

            var client = new RestClient("https://******/v1/profile/channels")
            {
                Timeout = -1
            };

            var apiRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

            apiRequest.AddHeader("client_id", "********4cedc");

            apiRequest.AddHeader("client_secret", "*******d526c");

            apiRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI*******");

            apiRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
         

            apiRequest.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var apiResponse = client.ExecuteAsync(apiRequest).Result;

            Console.WriteLine(apiResponse.Content);
```

With Postman it is working fine:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Perhaps the method should be POST rather than GET?

Comment: This is GET method, with postman I am able to call

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with [System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/) package that does support the functionality - simply installed and used when constructing my HttpClient instances.

```
var request = new GetAlertProfileDistributionChannelRequest
            {
                AccountCustomerNumber = "***0201",
                DistributionChannelSubscriptions = new AlertProfileDistributionChannelSubscriptions
                {
                    AlertProfileId = Guid.Parse("7adaaa2c-5b2d-424c-8dc8-4e9a01908729")
                }
            };

            var handler = new WinHttpHandler();
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);


            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_id", "**********5487");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_secret", "*******c99");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSU");
            var apirequest = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://*********profile/channels"),
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
                
            };

            var response = client.SendAsync(apirequest).Result;

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```